# @Injectable service does not seem to be a singleton

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an Angular service like so:

```
@Injectable
export class MyService {

  foo = true;

  fireTheCallback(){
    assert(this.foo === true); // this is correct
    this.cb();   // this.cb is not defined
  }

}
```

I inject that service into a component:

```
@Component({providers:[MyService]})
export class MyComponent {

 constructor(data: MyService){
     data.cb = v => {
        // attach this callback function to the service
     }
 }

}
```

after the service is created, we call `fireTheCallback()` but `this.cb` is not defined. It's *not* an issue of impromper context binding, because other variables like `foo` are set correctly. The problem appears to be that the Service gets recreated, so this.cb value gets lost.

Does anyone know why this might happen? I thought Services marked by @Injectable were singletons...what is going on here.

Comment: note that this question was motivated by this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143275/component-cannot-subscribe-to-data-source

Comment: In order to make it a singleton, it should be provided in a single place, typically in a module.

Comment: yeah thanks, I just figured that out, that was super confusing for a minute, I added an answer..

Comment: this design decision by Angular is going to cause some serious serious bugs in Angular apps. Your coworker is going to call providers:[X] and you are not going to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the reason why there was more than one instance of the class, was because I was using `providers:[MyService]` in more than one place.

So the solution is to call:

`providers:[MyService]`

just once, if you want MyService to be a singleton (you want only one instance of that class. best to make the providers call in your root module.

So you should call `@Inject(MyService)` as many times as you want, that will inject the same singleton everywhere.